# Find input onClick event and replace Value attribute

Tags: jquery, opencart

Guys this is a broad question, but I'll try to keep it simple.

Simply what I want to do is, look for a particular `onClick`, example `addToCart('57')`, and find replace the `Value` attribute of that particular input box containing `addToCart('57')` to `Added`.

I got the onclick event string using

```
var getOnClickValueForNotification = $('.cart input').attr("onclick");
```

But Im finding it hard to implement jquery `find` to look for `getOnClickValueForNotification` and replace `Value` attribute to `Added`.

Comment: Changing onclick attributes is so _hackish_, you can consider using `data-*` attributes and forget about `onclick` attributes.

Comment: You can use this in the onclick callback to know which item was clicked

Comment: Sorry everyone. If you misunderstood. I DONT want to change onClick attribute. I want to change the Value attribute of the input button.

Comment: I modified the question so it makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using the .on('click') event for the input (note, that there may already be an event attached to this input, so you will need to find and use that if so) and pass the event handler through to find the target of what was clicked.

Something like this should do the job.

```
$('.cart input').on('click', function(e){
    e.target.attr('value', 'Added');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The jQuery attr function sets the value of the given attribute in the first parameter when a second parameter is send.

```
$('.cart input').attr('onclick', 'Added');
```

This would change the onclick="addToCart('57')" to onclick="Added"

But I agree, using data-*something* to get and set values is better than relying on stuff like onclicks

Comment: I actually want to change the Value propert of the inpupt field, not the onClick property

Comment: Just change the 'onclick' for 'value' and it should work. But be careful the above code will change the value of all the dom elements that will match the selector, if you only want to change the value of the clicked input @Stann0rz code is the one to go for.